# Batch file for /f isnt reading files

Tags: windows, batch-file

Lots of issues With batch coding...  Things just don't seem to work the way i expect them to.

So I am Using a batch file to Extract Text data from .as Files. I managed to get that working However It creates a bunch of Junk/empty txt files that don't have any useful content extracted from them. So I made another batch file that gets called from main.bat and is supposed to Clean the empty files, however the variables are incorrect even though the for loop in main.bat is almost identical.

Full Copies of the batch files [main.bat](http://pastebin.com/e6k4c4jH) and [Clean.bat](http://pastebin.com/dsvDEh0x)

The Issue Is the Bit of Code below (From Clean.bat line 33) #note the following code had most of its counters and echos removed

`@echo off
cls
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /r %%Z in (*.txt) do (
    SET /a count=0
    for /F "eol= tokens=1 delims=," %%A in ("%%Z") do (
        if /i %%A==LN set /a count+=1
    )
    if !count! EQU 0 (
        rem del "%%Z")
)
pause`

In this Code %%A and %%Z Are both Equal to The Full File Path of the file that should be getting read from. When %%A should be token 1 of The txt file in question. Because of this count always = 0 so it always deletes the file (thats why del is commented out).

Here's an Example of the file its supposed to read from

`LN,296,textE("海沿いに立つ高級フィットネスリゾート施設。");
LN,299,textE("夏休み、俺たち兄妹は、陸上の強化合宿という「名目」のもと、\nこの施設を訪れていた。");
LN,302,textE("莉 央\nすごい、すごい！！おしゃれなところだねー！");`

Basically Its supposed to check each line and if LN doesnt Exist as the first token to any line it deletes the file. (Because that means the file is empty except for a Line count of the Original .as file)

Comment: Double quotes are used in `for /F` loops to process strings. To run through the contents of a file, you don't use any quotes. Change `%%A in ("%%Z") do` to `%%A in (%%Z) do`.

Comment: ... or add `usebackq` option in the list of `for` options. This is needed if the file names may contain spaces.

Comment: @SomethingDark  Your solution doesn't handle spaces etc in the filename\path and Aacini's suggestion solves that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may work for you given the things you have said:

I interpreted your point to mean that if the file doesn't contain `LN` as the first token on any line, then it is to be deleted.

```
@echo off
for /r %%Z in (*.txt) do (
    SET "count="
    for /F "usebackq delims=," %%A in ("%%Z") do (
        if /i "%%A"=="LN" set count=1
    )
    if not defined count echo del "%%Z"
)
pause
```

This is another way to do the same thing:

```
@echo off
for /r %%Z in (*.txt) do (
    findstr "^LN," "%%Z" >nul || echo del "%%Z"
)
pause
```

Comment: Thanks This works Nicely =) Still Not sure why mine doesn't work though. Also Yes you interpreted my point correctly, Hopefully I made sense =). I only started working with batch files so I'm still trying to figure out the syntax. 

Hopefully it will still work after I add in the echos.

Comment: Aacini commented above that spaces in the filename or path require that `usebackq` be added.  Your code may work with only that change - but the `if` compare can also break depending on the data in the files and the double quotes makes that more robust.  I removed the need for delayed expansion - which only matters when `!` characters need to be processed.